# How to access variables across multiple rake tasks with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, namespaces, rake

I've seen a few solutions that didn't seem to work for me. Suppose I have the following code-

```
  namespace :genie do

    task :test => :environment do
      test_user = User.find_or_create_by_username('test') do |i|
          i.email = 'email@email.com'
    end

    task :test_reset => :environment do

      test_user.update_attributes({
        :email => 'test@email.com',       
      })

    end
```

This code fails when running rake genie:test, rake genie:test_reset because test_user is not defined in the second rake task. How can I call test_user without having to define it each time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can encapsulate the definition of the user in a helper function.

```
namespace :genie do
  task :test => :environment do
    puts test_user.email
  end

  task :test_reset => :environment do
    test_user.update_attributes({
      :email => 'test@email.com',       
    })
  end
end

def test_user
  User.find_or_create_by_username('test') do |i|
    i.email = email@email.com
  end
end
```